# Problems establishing serial connection with beagle bone black on ttyUSB0

Tags: usb, arm, serial-port

I have tried using minicom, Putty, screen and cKermit to no avail.   It looks as if the connection is intermittent from the output of `dmesg | grep tty`.

```
[1627865.078080] usb 5-2: Product: AM335x USB
[1627865.078086] usb 5-2: Manufacturer: Texas Instruments
[1627865.152124] rndis_host 5-2:1.0: usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:13.0-2, RNDIS device, 9a:1f:85:1c:3d:0e
[1627865.398299] userif-2: sent link down event.
[1627865.398309] userif-2: sent link up event.<6>[1627905.546191] usb 5-2: USB disconnect, device number 41
[1627905.547204] rndis_host 5-2:1.0: usb0: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:13.0-2, RNDIS device
[1627905.748089] userif-2: sent link down event.
[1627905.748098] userif-2: sent link up event.<6>[1627910.599519] usb 5-2: new full-speed USB device number 42 using ohci_hcd
**[1627910.758329] usb 5-2: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[1627910.768319] usb 5-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0451, idProduct=6141
[1627910.768331] usb 5-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=33, Product=37, SerialNumber=0
[1627910.768340] usb 5-2: Product: AM335x USB
[1627910.768346] usb 5-2: Manufacturer: Texas Instruments
[1627910.842502] rndis_host 5-2:1.0: usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:13.0-2, RNDIS device, 9a:1f:85:1c:3d:0e
[1627911.082551] userif-2: sent link down event.
[1627911.082555] userif-2: sent link up event.<6>[1627921.042308] usb 5-2: USB disconnect, device number 42
[1627921.043378] rndis_host 5-2:1.0: usb0: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:13.0-2, RNDIS device**
[1627921.243451] userif-2: sent link down event.
[1627921.243461] userif-2: sent link up event.<6>[1627925.167815] usb 5-2: new full-speed USB device number 43 using ohci_hcd
[1627925.326657] usb 5-2: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[1627925.336645] usb 5-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0451, idProduct=6141
[1627925.336658] usb 5-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=33, Product=37, SerialNumber=0
[1627925.336666] usb 5-2: Product: AM335x USB
[1627925.336673] usb 5-2: Manufacturer: Texas Instruments
[1627925.411023] rndis_host 5-2:1.0: usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:13.0-2, RNDIS device, 9a:1f:85:1c:3d:0e
[1627925.665530] userif-2: sent link down event.
[1627925.665540] userif-2: sent link up event.<3>[1627960.208500] hub 5-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 3
[1627960.448125] usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 51 using ehci_hcd
[1627960.581809] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=14cd, idProduct=121f
[1627960.581814] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=2
[1627960.581816] usb 2-3: Product: Mass Storage Device
[1627960.581818] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Generic
[1627960.581820] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 121F20110712
[1627960.582540] scsi32 : usb-storage 2-3:1.0
[1627961.579368] scsi 32:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Mass     Storage Device   1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[1627961.580592] sd 32:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[1627961.871287] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdc] 15644672 512-byte logical blocks: (8.01 GB/7.45 GiB)
[1627961.871786] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[1627961.871799] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[1627961.872313] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[1627961.872325] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[1627961.875901] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[1627961.875913] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[1627961.876801]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2
[1627961.883007] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[1627961.883019] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[1627961.883028] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[1627987.679657] usb 5-2: USB disconnect, device number 43
[1627987.680127] rndis_host 5-2:1.0: usb0: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:13.0-2, RNDIS device
[1627987.880125] userif-2: sent link down event.
[1627987.880135] userif-2: sent link up event.<6>[1636287.932125] usb 2-3: USB disconnect, device number 51
[1636372.495480] usb 5-3: new full-speed USB device number 45 using ohci_hcd
[1636372.673303] usb 5-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001
[1636372.673316] usb 5-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
```

It looks like it is connected from this output but when I try to connect to `/dev/ttyUSB0` it doesn't recognize ttyUSB0.

I have tried changing the permissions also like it was suggested in another post to no avail.  When I am trying to connect with Putty at `/dev/ttyUSB0` with a speed of 115200 baud nothing happens visually when I click connect.

I am also using moserial but I do not see USB0 in it's drop down.  Any hints or direction on where to search is greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 3):

According to the  beaglebone [support site](http://beagleboard.org/getting-started) you do not need any special drivers for it to work on linux, but you might need to run the script (`mkudevrule.sh`) they provide to create some udev rules. And check your USB cable for proper contact (I know it sound trivial but it only takes a few seconds to check and can save you lots of hours of troubleshooting.)

Comment: Thanks.  Using `mkudevrule.sh` fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, turned out to be the mini-usb cable (probably wasn't providing enough power). You may want to try with the shortest cable you find.